# Implement autofill service in android app

Tags: java, android, autofill

I'm trying to build a password manager application. During the process I've come across a problem: implementing the autofill functionality that other password managers use in their app to let the user easily fill their credentials on a website or in an app. Does anyone know how I can implement this functionality in android studio?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwncJ.jpg)

Comment: This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services) and, to an extent, in [this free older book](https://commonsware.com/Android/). If you run into specific problems, feel free to ask specific questions here at Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

The first place you will need to start is the AutofillService guide :[Build Autofill Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services) in order to understand: AndroidManifest requirements (BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE), permissions, and requirements for your implementation of Autofill service.

Code samples:

- Android [Input samples](https://github.com/android/input-samples/tree/main/AutofillFramework) (3 years old)
- [Android PasswordStore](https://github.com/android-password-store/Android-Password-Store/blob/35155e55841bc87b2c0e0dc577e1433041b44bc5/app/src/main/java/dev/msfjarvis/aps/util/services/OreoAutofillService.kt) (Best .kt Implementation)

Issues you will run into, targetSDK matching your emulator, and after Android 12 the Autofill Service settings menu seems unreachable through the OS but it is actually: Passwords & Accounts -> Aufofill Section and click Google to select a different one. .

Best of luck.